# Injecting contextual data in Resteasy tests with Netty

Tags: java, integration-testing, netty, resteasy

I'm trying to test a resource with Resteasy using an embedded Netty instance as described in the [Resteasy Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Embedded_Container.html#d4e1403).

Injecting path parameters and query parameters works like a charm but then I tried to test a resource that injects `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` from the context like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public void example(@Context HttpServletResponse response, 
                    @Context HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

Resteasy cannot find `HttpServletRequest`in the context and throws the following exception:

```
5105 [r #1] DEB o.j.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher  - PathInfo: /auth
5201 [r #1] ERR c.s.f.v.s.r.e.ApplicationExceptionMapper - Unhandled application exception: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

I tried putting mock versions of request and response in the context as suggested in [RESTEasy Mock vs. Exception Mapper vs. Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136780/resteasy-mock-vs-exception-mapper-vs-context) but it does not work either as the contextual data is a ThreadLocal and Netty spawns a new thread for each request.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: There is a bug filed to track this, but it's quite old:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got hit by this again on another project and decided to investigate once more.

The issue is that in a mock request with Netty, there is no `HttpServletRequest` available. If you look into the sources of `NettyJaxrsServer`and related classes, Reasteasy uses its own abstraction for http requests that do not implement `HttpServletRequest`.

If I change my implementation to use these abstractions, I can access request and response in my resource.

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse;

@GET
@Path("/")
public void example(@Context HttpResponse response, 
                    @Context HttpRequest request) { ... }
```

This is not perfect, because it makes my resources depend on Resteasy interfaces but I decided to go with it for now to support mock testing of multipart data.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case was injecting a org.jboss.seam.mock.HttpServletRequest, since I am using seam in my application. You should try some mock framework like spring.test or mockito.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory;
import org.jboss.seam.mock.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.jboss.seam.mock.DBUnitSeamTest;

public class Test extends DBUnitSeamTest{   

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();

        POJOResourceFactory noDefaults = new POJOResourceFactory(ClasstoBeTested.class);        dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(noDefaults);
        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/serviceToBeTested/1961");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest(getSession());
        ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextDataMap().put(HttpServletRequest.class, servletRequest);

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        Assert.assertEquals(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, response.getStatus());
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getContentAsString().contains("1961")); 

    }
}
```

Comment: This works for simple scenarios like request parameters but makes it much harder to test things like multipart uploads. I'm using restassured to test my JAX-RS resources and I would have to mock out the multiparts in my requests as well.